# How do you escape strings for SQLite table/column names in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

The standard approach for using variable values in SQLite queries is the "question mark style", like this:

```py
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as connection:
    connection.execute("CREATE TABLE foo(bar)")
    connection.execute("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES (?)", ("cow",))

    print(list(connection.execute("SELECT * from foo")))
    # prints [(u'cow',)]
```

However, this only works for substituting values into queries. It fails when used for table or column names:

```py
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as connection:
    connection.execute("CREATE TABLE foo(?)", ("bar",))
    # raises sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Neither the `sqlite3` module nor [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) mention a function for escaping names or values. Presumably this is to discourage users from assembling their queries with strings, but it leaves me at a loss.

What function or technique is most appropriate for using variable names for columns or tables in SQLite? I'd would strongly prefer to do able to do this without any other dependencies, since I'll be using it in my own wrapper.

I looked for but couldn't find a clear and complete description of the relevant part of SQLite's syntax, to use to write my own function. I want to be sure this will work for any identifier permitted by SQLite, so a trial-and-error solution is too uncertain for me.

SQLite [uses `"` to quote identifiers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) but I'm not sure that just escaping them is sufficient. PHP's [`sqlite_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-escape-string.php) function's documentation suggests that certain binary data may need to be escaped as well, but that may be a quirk of the PHP library.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To convert any string into a SQLite identifier:

- Ensure the string can be encoded as UTF-8.
- Ensure the string does not include any NUL characters.
- Replace all `"` with `""`.
- Wrap the entire thing in double quotes.

#### Implementation

```python
import codecs

def quote_identifier(s, errors="strict"):
    encodable = s.encode("utf-8", errors).decode("utf-8")

    nul_index = encodable.find("\x00")

    if nul_index >= 0:
        error = UnicodeEncodeError("NUL-terminated utf-8", encodable,
                                   nul_index, nul_index + 1, "NUL not allowed")
        error_handler = codecs.lookup_error(errors)
        replacement, _ = error_handler(error)
        encodable = encodable.replace("\x00", replacement)

    return "\"" + encodable.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""
```

Given a string single argument, it will escape and quote it correctly or raise an exception. The second argument can be used to specify any error handler registered in [the `codecs` module](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html). The built-in ones are:

> - `'strict'`: raise an exception in case of an encoding error
> - `'replace'`: replace malformed data with a suitable replacement marker, such as `'?'` or `'\ufffd'`
> - `'ignore'`: ignore malformed data and continue without further notice
> - `'xmlcharrefreplace'`: replace with the appropriate XML character reference (for encoding only)
> - `'backslashreplace'`: replace with backslashed escape sequences (for encoding only)

This doesn't check for reserved identifiers, so if you try to create a new `SQLITE_MASTER` table it won't stop you.

#### Example Usage

```python
import sqlite3

def test_identifier(identifier):
    "Tests an identifier to ensure it's handled properly."

    with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as c:
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE " + quote_identifier(identifier) + " (foo)")
        assert identifier == c.execute("SELECT name FROM SQLITE_MASTER").fetchone()[0]

test_identifier("'Héllo?'\\\n\r\t\"Hello!\" -☃") # works
test_identifier("北方话") # works
test_identifier(chr(0x20000)) # works

print(quote_identifier("Fo\x00o!", "replace")) # prints "Fo?o!"
print(quote_identifier("Fo\x00o!", "ignore")) # prints "Foo!"
print(quote_identifier("Fo\x00o!")) # raises UnicodeEncodeError
print(quote_identifier(chr(0xD800))) # raises UnicodeEncodeError
```

#### Observations and References

- SQLite identifiers are [`TEXT`](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses), not binary.

  - [`SQLITE_MASTER` schema in the FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7)
  - Python 2 SQLite API yelled at me when I gave it bytes it couldn't decode as text.
  - Python 3 SQLite API requires queries be `str`s, not `bytes`.

- SQLite identifiers are quoted using double-quotes.

  - [SQL as Understood by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

- Double-quotes in SQLite identifiers are escaped as two double quotes.

- SQLite identifiers preserve case, but they are case-insensitive towards ASCII letters. It is possible to enable unicode-aware case-insensitivity.

  - [SQLite FAQ Question #18](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18)

- SQLite does not support the [NUL character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) in strings or identifiers.

  - [SQLite Ticket 57c971fc74](http://www.sqlite.org/src/tktview?name=57c971fc74)

- `sqlite3` can handle any other unicode string as long as it can be properly encoded to UTF-8. Invalid strings could cause crashes between Python 3.0 and Python 3.1.2 or thereabouts. Python 2 accepted these invalid strings, but this is considered a bug.

  - [Python Issue #12569](http://bugs.python.org/issue12569)
  - [Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/42ec507815d2/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c)
  - I tested it a bunch.

Comment: Further on the issue of case insensitivity in the ASCII range: for an arbitrary string to be converted, some custom escaping can be used, for example: `A-Z -> &a-&z` and `& -> &&`.

Comment: Since your answer seems the most comprehensive on this topic, if you happen to know, perhaps you could add mention of restrictions or special handling of the empty string (especially since the likes of IndexedDB do allow it as an identifier). I see some implementation treat empty strings as a temporary database.

Comment: Such a great and comprehensive answer! Not related directly to escaping, but I think it worth to add clarification to statement "_SQLite identifiers are quoted using double-quotes_." - it also allows single quotes, square brackets and grave accents ('', [], ``)

Answer (score 31):

The `psycopg2` documentation explicitly recommends using normal python % or {} formatting to substitute in table and column names (or other bits of dynamic syntax), and then using the parameter mechanism to substitute values into the query.

I disagree with everyone who is saying "don't ever use dynamic table/column names, you're doing something wrong if you need to". I write programs to automate stuff with databases every day, and I do it all the time. We have lots of databases with lots of tables, but they are all built on repeated patterns, so generic code to handle them is *extremely* useful. Hand-writing the queries every time would be far more error prone and dangerous.

It comes down to what "safe" means. The conventional wisdom is that using normal python string manipulation to put values into your queries is not "safe". This is because there are all sorts of things that can go wrong if you do that, and such data very often comes from the user and is not in your control. You need a 100% reliable way of escaping these values properly so that a user cannot inject SQL in a data value and have the database execute it. So the library writers do this job; you never should.

If, however, you're writing generic helper code to operate on things in databases, then these considerations don't apply as much. You are implicitly giving anyone who can call such code access to everything in the database; **that's the point of the helper code**. So now the safety concern is making sure that user-generated data can never be used in such code. This is a general security issue in coding, and is just the same problem as blindly `exec`ing a user-input string. It's a distinct issue from inserting *values* into your queries, because there you **want** to be able to *safely* handle user-input data.

So my recommendation is: do whatever you want to dynamically assemble your queries. Use normal python string templating to sub in table and column names, glue on where clauses and joins, all the good (and horrible to debug) stuff. But make sure you're aware that whatever values such code touches has to come from **you**, not your users[1]. Then you use SQLite's parameter substitution functionality to *safely* insert user-input values into your queries as values.

[1] If (as is the case for a lot of the code I write) your users *are* the people who have full access to databases anyway and the code is to simplify their work, then this consideration doesn't really apply; you probably are assembling queries on user-specified tables. But you should still use SQLite's parameter substitution to save yourself from the inevitable genuine value that eventually contains quotes or percent signs.

Comment: It's much less necessary though. Anyone who wants to name a table "My '%shiny%' table" **is** doing it wrong. Table and column names are usually simple strings that would be valid identifiers in most programming languages, so they're not going to accidentally explode. And you throw security out the window if you give users the ability to pass table names into your application anyway, so you don't do that.

Comment: How do you sanitize the column names? As much as I understand, removing brackets and bracketing the column name should be ok, but is theer something that sqlite itself considers safe?

Comment: @peterchen Are the column names coming from "you"? (i.e. generated from constants in the program, or some other controlled source) Or are they coming from an external source that might contain weird names? If they come from you, I'd just make the names you generate are valid identifiers. If you're getting untrustworthy input to use as column names, I personally would be inclined to be ruthless; lowercase everything, then replace everything except letters and numbers with underscores.

Comment: what does `psycopg2` have to do with sqlite?

Comment: @Michael Nothing. I was merely citing psycopg2 as a reasonably respected source who agrees with the contention in the rest of my post; that ordinary string templating operations are usually sufficient for inserting table/column names into queries.

Answer (score 17):

If you're quite certain that you need to specify column names dynamically, you should use a library that can do so safely (and complains about things that are wrong).  SQLAlchemy is very good at that.

```
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> metadata = MetaData()
>>> dynamic_column = "cow"
>>> foo_table = Table('foo', metadata,
...     Column(dynamic_column, Integer))
>>>
```

`foo_table` now *represents* the table with the dynamic schema, but you can only use it in the context of an actual database connection (so that sqlalchemy knows the dialect, and what to do with the generated sql).

```
>>> metadata.bind = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
```

You can then issue the `CREATE TABLE ...`.  with `echo=True`, sqlalchemy will *log* the generated sql, but in general, sqlalchemy goes out of its way to keep the generated sql out of your hands (lest you consider using it for evil purposes).

```
>>> foo_table.create()
2011-06-28 21:54:54,040 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...2f4c 
CREATE TABLE foo (
    cow INTEGER
)
2011-06-28 21:54:54,040 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...2f4c ()
2011-06-28 21:54:54,041 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...2f4c COMMIT
>>>
```

and yes, sqlalchemy will take care of any column names that need special handling, like when the column name is a sql reserved word

```
>>> dynamic_column = "order"
>>> metadata = MetaData()
>>> foo_table = Table('foo', metadata,
...     Column(dynamic_column, Integer))
>>> metadata.bind = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
>>> foo_table.create()
2011-06-28 22:00:56,267 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...aa8c 
CREATE TABLE foo (
    "order" INTEGER
)
2011-06-28 22:00:56,267 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...aa8c ()
2011-06-28 22:00:56,268 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...aa8c COMMIT
>>>
```

and can save you from possible badness:

```
>>> dynamic_column = "); drop table users; -- the evil bobby tables!"
>>> metadata = MetaData()
>>> foo_table = Table('foo', metadata,
...     Column(dynamic_column, Integer))
>>> metadata.bind = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
>>> foo_table.create()
2011-06-28 22:04:22,051 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...05ec 
CREATE TABLE foo (
    "); drop table users; -- the evil bobby tables!" INTEGER
)
2011-06-28 22:04:22,051 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...05ec ()
2011-06-28 22:04:22,051 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...05ec COMMIT
>>>
```

(apparently, some strange things are perfectly legal identifiers in sqlite)

Comment: The poster said he wanted no additional dependencies, but since SQLAlchemy is open source this is still a great example of where to look to find out what you need to do to really do it right.

Answer (score 9):

The **first** thing to understand is that table/column names *cannot* be escaped in the same sense than you can escape strings stored as database values.

The reason is that you either have to:

- accept/reject the potential table/column name, i.e. it is not guaranteed that a string is an acceptable column/table name, contrarily to a string to be stored in some database; or,
- sanitize the string which will have the same effect as creating a digest: the function used is [surjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function), not [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) (once again, the inverse is true for a string that is to be stored in some database); so not only can't you be certain of going from the sanitized name back to the original name, but you are at risk of unintentionally trying to create two columns or tables with the same name.

Having understood that, the **second** thing to understand is that how you will end up "escaping" table/column names depends on your specific context, and so there is more than one way to do this, but whatever the way, you'll need to dig up to figure out exactly what is or is not an acceptable column/table name in sqlite.

To get you started, here is one condition:

> Table names that begin with "sqlite_" are reserved for internal use. It is an error to attempt to create a table with a name that starts with "sqlite_".

Even better, using certain column names can have unintended side effects:

> Every row of every SQLite table has a 64-bit signed integer key that
>   uniquely identifies the row within its table. This integer is usually
>   called the "rowid". The rowid value can be accessed using one of the
>   special case-independent names "rowid", "oid", or "*rowid*" in place
>   of a column name. If a table contains a user defined column named
>   "rowid", "oid" or "*rowid*", then that name always refers the
>   explicitly declared column and cannot be used to retrieve the integer
>   rowid value.

Both quoted texts are from http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 6):

From the [sqlite faq, question 24](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q24) (the formulation of the question of course does not give a clue that the answer may be useful to your question):

> SQL uses double-quotes around identifiers (column or table names) that contains special characters or which are keywords. So double-quotes are a way of escaping identifier names.

If the name itself contains double quotes, escape that double quote with another one.

Comment: +1, thanks. I don't think it's a complete solution, though, because the PHP functions for escaping SQLite values also escapes certain binary values (I couldn't understand the details) and I think that may also be necessary here.

Comment: Binary values in table/column names? Not sure what you mean there... (sounds to me like those functions are meant for values rather than table or column names, and even then, it would be a strange thing to use instead of sqlite's "question mark" parameter substitution)

Comment: @Stephen That function is meant for values instead of names, but it suggests to me that it may also be possible to include binary data in names in theory, which would be an unhanded edge case if I only escaped double-quotes.

Comment: Did some googling... are you referring to sqlite_escape_string? That one doesn't seem to be meant for (or even fit for) escaping table/column names as far as I can tell, but maybe someone with PHP knowledge can provide some more info?

Comment: @Stephen I am and you're right. I'm not saying that that is the PHP equivalent of what I'm looking for; I'm saying that because values need to have certain bytes escaped it seems likely that names also need to have those bytes escaped.

Comment: I don't think this will be an issue, because - if I'm not mistaken - it won't even be possible to have names like that in your database (I don't suppose sql standard allows this, and I'd be surprised if sqlite did)

Comment: @Stephen That may be the case, but I haven't been able to find anything confirming that behaviour. I'd like to be *sure* that the function will behave properly for all allowed identifiers.

Answer (score 5):

Placeholders are only for values.  Column and table names are structural, and are akin to variable names; you can't use placeholders to fill them in.

You have three options:

1. Appropriately escape/quote the column name everywhere you use it.  This is fragile and dangerous.
2. Use an ORM like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), which will take care of escaping/quoting for you.
3. Ideally, just don't have dynamic column names.  Tables and columns are for *structure*; anything dynamic is *data* and should be in the table rather than part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I made some research because I was unsatisfied with the current unsafe answers, and I would recommend using the internal `printf` function of sqlite to do that. It is made to escape any identifier (table name, column table...) and make it safe for concatenation.

In python, it should be something like that (I'm not a python user, so there may be mistakes, but the logic itself works):

```py
table = "bar"
escaped_table = connection.execute("SELECT printf('%w', ?)", (table,)).fetchone()[0]
connection.execute("CREATE TABLE \""+escaped_table+"\" (bar TEXT)")
```

According to the [documentation of %w](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html#percentw):

> This substitution works like %q except that it doubles all double-quote characters (") instead of single-quotes, making the result suitable for using with a double-quoted identifier name in an SQL statement.
>
> The %w substitution is an SQLite enhancements, not found in most other printf() implementations.

Which means you can alternatively do the same with single quotes using `%q`:

```py
table = "bar"
escaped_table = connection.execute("SELECT printf('%q', ?)", (table,)).fetchone()[0]
connection.execute("CREATE TABLE '"+escaped_table+"' (bar TEXT)")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you find that you need a variable entity name (either relvar or field) then you probably are doing something *wrong*.  an alternative pattern would be to use a property map, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_properties(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, name)
);
```

Then, you just specify the name dynamically when doing an insert instead of a column.

Comment: I do not see a reason why this was downvoted, without daring to vote it up now. Does it not work? Since, if this trick is working, so that I get the column names from an existing property table without having to mind which column name might be a keyword, then what is so bad about this idea?