# Can't escape table or column names when importing data model from XML using SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you escape strings for SQLite table/column names in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514274/how-do-you-escape-strings-for-sqlite-table-column-names-in-python)

I would like to import an entire data model from an XML file using SQLite, and while I know how to programmatically insert/escape values using the `?` syntax in queries, this does not work for the names of tables or columns when creating those. I could simply put that in the query string using Python, however this doesn't feel right and I would think there would be a proper way to insert these values so that they are escaped, to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [posted a solution that seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514274/how-do-you-escape-strings-for-sqlite-table-column-names-in-python#6701665) in the other question. Here's the function:

```python
def quote_identifier(s, errors="strict"):
    encodable = s.encode("utf-8", errors).decode("utf-8")

    nul_index = encodable.find("\x00")

    if nul_index >= 0:
        error = UnicodeEncodeError("NUL-terminated utf-8", encodable,
                                   nul_index, nul_index + 1, "NUL not allowed")
        error_handler = codecs.lookup_error(errors)
        replacement, _ = error_handler(error)
        encodable = encodable.replace("\x00", replacement)

    return "\"" + encodable.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""
```

It doesn't warn you about reserved identifiers, so you have to worry about that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514274/how-do-you-escape-strings-for-sqlite-table-column-names-in-python). It doesn't look like there's any way to do what you're asking through the sqlite module(s). Most people just include the table name literally. If you're really paranoid, you could write a function to see if a table name looks valid, maybe something like:

```
import string

def isValidTableName(name):
    allowed_chs = string.letters + string.digits + '_'
    return len(name) == len([ch for ch in name if ch in allowed_chs])
```

Table names are generally limited to letters, numbers, and underscores, so this would be a reasonable way to check for injection. Just don't let anything that doesn't pass through.