# Sqlite3 statement creating table named parameters

Tags: python, sqlite

say i want to create a table in sqlite3 with 3 columns,

```
tableparams = { "data" : "varchar" , "col2" : "char", "col3" : "integer" }
c = """create table mytesttable ( ? )"""
cur.executemany(c, tableparams )
```

I can't seem to get it done. The sql is supposed to be

```
create table myteststable ( data varchar, col2 char, col3 integer)
```

How can i "expand" out those params to be passed to executemany()? thanks

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/a/6701665/8747 useful.

Answer (score 1):

Only SQL values (numbers, strings, blobs) can be replaced by parameters.

Anything else must be written directly into the string:

```
cur.execute("create table myteststable ( data varchar, col2 char, col3 integer)")
```