# Substituting column names in Python sqlite3 query

Tags: python, security, sqlite

I have a wide table in a sqlite3 database, and I wish to dynamically query certain columns in a Python script. I know that [it's bad to inject parameters by string concatenation](http://xkcd.com/327/), so I tried to use parameter substitution instead.

I find that, when I use parameter substitution to supply a column name, I get unexpected results. A minimal example:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

db = lite.connect("mre.sqlite")
c = db.cursor()

# Insert some dummy rows
c.execute("CREATE TABLE trouble (value real)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO trouble (value) VALUES (2)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO trouble (value) VALUES (4)")
db.commit()


for row in c.execute("SELECT AVG(value) FROM trouble"):
    print row   # Returns 3

for row in c.execute("SELECT AVG(:name) FROM trouble", {"name" : "value"}):
    print row   # Returns 0

db.close()
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this than simply injecting a column name into a string and running it?

Comment: Agreed, that's the answer!

Comment: Even better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514274/how-do-you-escape-strings-for-sqlite-table-column-names-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob just indicated in his comment, there was a related SO post that contains my answer. These substitution constructions are called "placeholders," which is why I did not find the answer on SO initially. There is no placeholder pattern for column names, because [dynamically specifying columns is not a code safety issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514274/how-do-you-escape-strings-for-sqlite-table-column-names-in-python):

> It comes down to what "safe" means. The conventional wisdom is that
>   using normal python string manipulation to put values into your
>   queries is not "safe". This is because there are all sorts of things
>   that can go wrong if you do that, and such data very often comes from
>   the user and is not in your control. You need a 100% reliable way of
>   escaping these values properly so that a user cannot inject SQL in a
>   data value and have the database execute it. So the library writers do
>   this job; you never should.
>
> If, however, you're writing generic helper code to operate on things
>   in databases, then these considerations don't apply as much. You are
>   implicitly giving anyone who can call such code access to everything
>   in the database; that's the point of the helper code. So now the
>   safety concern is making sure that user-generated data can never be
>   used in such code. This is a general security issue in coding, and is
>   just the same problem as blindly execing a user-input string. It's a
>   distinct issue from inserting values into your queries, because there
>   you want to be able to safely handle user-input data.

So, the solution is that there is no problem in the first place: inject the values using string formatting, be happy, and move on with your life.

Comment: "This isn't a security hole" does not mean "there isn't a problem". Giving the caller an error message that isn't confusing is certainly a problem. As is eliminating accidentally correct syntax that results from typos.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use string formatting?

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT AVG({name}) FROM trouble".format(**{"name" : "value"})):
    print row # => (3.0,)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's actually what I meant by injecting the column name into the string; sorry if that wasn't clear.