# SYNTAX ERROR FOR SQLITE VARIABLE PASSING COMMAND?

Tags: python, sqlite

i am using sqlite3 with python and want the data of my colomn "Pcode" and the situation is that "Pcode" is stored in a variable say "b"

```
        b= "Pcode"
        b = str(b)
        c.execute('''SELECT ? FROM AddStock''',(b,))
        results = c.fetchall()
        print(results)
```

the expected results are as follows

```
[('***data from database***',), ('***data from database***',)]
```

but getting the result as :

```
[('Pcode',), ('Pcode',)]
```

and i dont know why iam getting this type of results?

Comment: Just trying to rule out the obvious have you tried hard coding it I.E. c.execute('SELECT Pcode FROM AddStock')?

Comment: thanks buddy but i get the result in another way

Comment: That query returns the parameter value for every row in the table. You can't pass table or column names as parameters. In a database, the query is *not* executed as is. It's compiled into an execution plan based on the table statistics, the column types, indexes etc. Different tables, columns, statistics, indexes result in *very* different execution plans.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345378/substituting-column-names-in-python-sqlite3-query

Answer (score 0):

use the python script methord to add the variable in list

```
c.execute("SELECT "+b+" FROM AddStock")
```

this is the syntax for the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sqlite3, this code gives me the correct rows:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
b= "Pcode"
b = str(b)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT ? FROM AddStock''',(b,))

print(cur.fetchall())
```

Comment: no bro its not working it will also give the same unexpected result

Comment: Did you check the DB file using SQLITE browser? Maybe the data is not there?

Comment: i got the result and the output for your code is like this contain [((result1,),) ,((result2,),)] in which if i store in a var say 'a' and call for a[0] resul are "(result1,)," even paranthese and commas are included.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue, can you provide the db file and the code of the function?

Comment: i got the answer you can see below Answer :-)