# How do you escape strings for SQLite table names in c?

Tags: c, sqlite

How do you escape strings for SQLite table names in c?

I find a document, but it do not tell me the detail https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

And this document says that sql is end with '\x00' https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html

Here is the similar question in python: [How do you escape strings for SQLite table/column names in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514274/how-do-you-escape-strings-for-sqlite-table-column-names-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

- `example` to `'example'`
- `'a` to `'''a'`

Detail:

- Do not use the byte value 0 in the string.It will return an error like `unrecognized token: "'"` even if you pass the correct zSql len to sqlite3_prepare_v2().
- Replace `'` to `''` in the string, add `'` to the start and the end to the string. `'` is single quote (byte 39).
- It is not recommend to use invalid utf8 string. The string do not need to be valid utf8 string according to the parse code in sqlite3 version 3.28.0 . I have tested that invalid utf8 string can use as table name, but the document of sqlite3_prepare_v2() says you need `SQL statement, UTF-8 encoded`
- I have write a program to confirm that any byte list with len 1,2 without byte value 0 in it, can use as the table name, and the program can read value from that table, can list the table from the `SQLITE_MASTER` table in sqlite3 version 3.28.0.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers should be wrapped in double quotes if they need escaping, with all double quotes in them escaped by doubling up the quotes. `bad"name"` needs to become `"bad""name"` to be used in a SQL statement.

Sqlite comes with [custom versions of `*printf()` functions](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html) that include formats for escaping sql identifiers and strings (Which use single quotes in SQL). The one that does the escaping of double quotes for identifiers is `%w`:

```
char *sanitized_ddl = sqlite3_mprintf("CREATE TABLE \"%w\"(\"%w\", \"%w\");",
                                      "bad\"name", "foo bar", "baz");
```

Ideally, though, you're not going to use table or column names that *need* escaping, but it's good practice to escape user-supplied names to help protect against SQL injection attacks and the like.

Comment: "Ideally, though, you're not going to use table or column names that need escaping" No, I will not escape user-supplied names in the sql. I will always use the sqlite3_bind_blob() to pass my data into the sqlite3, but I can not use sqlite3_bind_blob to pass the table name. so I need find a way to escape them or encode them with hex.

Comment: "Identifiers should be wrapped in double quotes if they need escaping" where this message come from? As the c use double quotes already , i would like to use single quotes. And there is a compile options to disable double quotes: https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#dqs . I think double quotes is not first choose.